# Suppress command output lines that contain a certain string

Tags: command-line, text-processing

When I run an arbitrary command in the terminal in linux, is there a way to suppress output messages that contain a certain sentence?

I tried

```
./mycommand | grep -v "I dont want to see this"
```

but the messages were still there.

Comment: I guess you want `./mycommand |& grep -v "I dont want to see this"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the unwanted part is part of the output to stderr but to stdout.

Try:

```
./mycommand 2>&1 | grep -v "I dont want to see this"
```

---

You can pipe stderr and stdout to different targets. So you may see where the output comes from:

./mycommand > >(grep -v "I dont want to see this" > stdout.log)  2> >(grep -v "I dont want to see this" > stderr.log)

Comment: Also note that Bash has `|&`, which is a shorthand for `2>&1 |`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, but now it appears to print blank lines instead of those messages.

Comment: It appears to be a command-specific problem.  It outputs an error message and a blank line right after it.  Now that I filter out the messages, it only outputs the blank lines.
Is there a way to get rid of those lines too?

Comment: pipe the stderr and stdout to different files to see where the empty lines come from - I did an edit to explain how

Comment: I was able to filter out blank lines and unwanted messages using
`./mycommand 2>&1 | grep -v -e '^$' -e 'unwanted message'`
where `-e '^$'` checks for empty lines and `-e 'unwanted message'` checks for the messages that I want to suppress.

Comment: How can I do this while still forwarding the return status of `mycommand` ?

Answer (score 1):

To add to cmks' answer, if you also want the return code to be the one from `mycommand` and not from `grep`, you can use `pipefail` and ignore the return status from `grep` (for when the string to suppress isn't found)

```
(set -o pipefail; (./mycommand  2>&1) | { grep -v "I dont want to see this" || true; })
```

Examples:

- `(set -o pipefail; (echo "REMOVE" && false 2>&1) | { grep -v "REMOVE" || true; })`

  - stdout: nada
  - return: `1`
- `(set -o pipefail; (echo "REMOVE" && true 2>&1) | { grep -v "REMOVE" || true; })`

  - stdout: nada
  - return: `0`
- `(set -o pipefail; (echo "KEEP" && false 2>&1) | { grep -v "REMOVE" || true; })`

  - stdout: `KEEP`
  - return: `1`
- `(set -o pipefail; (echo "KEEP" && true 2>&1) | { grep -v "REMOVE" || true; })`

  - stdout: `KEEP`
  - return: `0`